# Find maximum of each row in a numpy array and the corresponding element in another array of the same size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Python and still cannot call myself a Python programmer. Speaking of that, please bear with me if my question does not make any sense.

## Question:

I have two numpy arrays of the same size, e.g. A and B where A.shape equals B.shape and they both equal (5,1000), and I want to find the maximum value of each row in A and the corresponding element of that in B. For instance, if in fourth row of A, maximum element index is 104 then I would like to find the 104th element of fourth row in array B and the same for the rest of the rows.

I know I can do it by looping over the rows but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it. For example, if I were to do it in MATLAB I would write the following code:

```
B(bsxfun(@eq,A,max(A,[],2)))
```

Any help that guides me through the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the `numpy` idiom for doing the same thing:

```
b[np.arange(len(a)), np.argmax(a, axis=1)]
```

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 0],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2]
    ])
>>> b = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3]
    ])
>>> b[np.arange(len(a)), np.argmax(a, axis=1)]
array([2, 1, 3])
```

Comment: good answer (+1), what about trying to build a solution using `np.argpartition`?

Comment: That was smart! That is why I am starting to love Python. You can do complicated stuff with simple commands!

Answer (score 1):

Being a [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) lover, it's great to see people trying to replicate the same functionality to other programming languages. Now, `bsxfun` is basically a [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) mechanism, which exists in NumPy as well. In NumPy, it is achieved by creating singleton dimensions with [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) or simply `None`.

Back to the question in context, an `equivalent` broadcasting based solution could be implemented as shown as a sample run -

```
In [128]: A
Out[128]: 
array([[40, 63, 67, 65, 19],
       [85, 55, 66, 92, 88],
       [50,  1, 23,  6, 59],
       [67, 55, 46, 78,  3]])

In [129]: B
Out[129]: 
array([[78, 63, 45, 34, 81],
       [ 5, 38, 28, 61, 66],
       [ 3, 65, 16, 25, 32],
       [72,  1, 31, 75,  6]])

In [130]: B[A == A.max(axis=1)[:,None]]
Out[130]: array([45, 61, 32, 75])
```

Answer (score 0):

`print np.max(A[i])` This will give the highest in the `i` th row of a `numpy` matrix.